# I can't trigger validations in Restful API tests using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to trigger validations in some Laravel Restful API methods in variable `$validations`, but I'm not having success in my attempts. It is only possible to correctly enter the fields so that the record can be inserted and updated.

```
    public function store(BloodTypeRequest $request)
    {
        $validations = $request->validated();

        $treated_datas = [
            'description' => trim((string) $validations['description']),
        ];

        $bt = BloodTypeModel::create($treated_datas);

        return response()->json($bt, 201);
    }

    public function update(BloodTypeRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $bt = BloodTypeModel::find($id);

        if (!$bt) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Register not found to update.'], 404);
        }

        $validations = $request->validated();

        $treated_datas = [
            'description' => trim((string) $validations['description']),
        ];

        BloodTypeModel::where('id', $id)->update($treated_datas);

        return response()->json($bt, 201);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `validated` method does not trigger validation, that simply returns data fields that have been validated. Validation has been done before inside that `BloodTypeRequest` form request.

If you want to trigger validation manually, pls [manually create a validator](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#manually-creating-validators.), or call the validate method from a normal request object.

```php
public function action()
{
    request()->validate();
}

// Or
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function action(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate();
}
```